# Using chemical weapons

Tags: word-usage

Suppose during a battle between two countries, the opposite country's fighters used chemical weapons; following the bombardment a soldier notices that the opponent side has dropped chemical bombs; then I wonder if you could tell me which one of the following sentences seems to be a bit **unnatural** to be said by the soldier in my scenario:

> - Run away! They hit us with chemical weapons.
> - Run away! They dropped chemical bombs.

Comment: Both look good to me. The first one sounds a bit more colloquial, and so fits pretty well for infantry that are stressed.

Comment: The choice of past over present perfect seems to be a sociolect feature.  "Get your asses outta here" seems more likely than "Run away".

Comment: "Chemical bombs" sounds off, as WBT says. "Chemical weapons" is idiomatic, but somewhat technical. In the heat of battle I'd expect something like "gas" or some more specific term for the type of weapon the victims think is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Chemical *bombs*" seems a bit off to me as a native speaker.
"Chemical *weapons*" would sound more natural.

The other difference between your examples is the difference between "*hit us with*" and "*dropped*."
"Dropped" implies that the weapons were deployed from aircraft while "hit us with" is ambiguous about how they were deployed (e.g. could have been on a rocket or thrown).
"Hit us with" implies that the weapons reached their target while "dropped" does not necessarily imply a hit.  (Context like "Run away!" implies they were at least close.)